# implementing breadth first search using CLRS in C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement breadth first search algorithm provided in CLRS. I am new to STL and require help in add edge function. Here I am trying to push nodes in adjency list.

```
enum eNodecolor{
    WHITE,
    GREY,
    BLACK
};

struct sVertex{
    int        m_iValue;
    eNodecolor m_visited;

public:

    sVertex(int iValue) {
        m_iValue = iValue;
    }


};


class CGraph {
private:

    std::map<sVertex, vector<sVertex*> > m_mapAdjList;
    int m_iNoOfVertices;

public:

    CGraph(int iNoOfVertices) {
        m_iNoOfVertices = iNoOfVertices;

    }

    void addEdge(int iDataForSource,  int iDataForDestination);

    ~CGraph(void){}

    void bfs();
};

/* user will call function add edge with source data and destination data. */

void CGraph::addEdge(int iDataForSource, int iDataForDestination) {



        // check if vertex exists in map if not create it
        // Question: How can I check here if data for source exists in map. 
        // if not exists create vertex
    sVertex* src = new sVertex(iDataForSource);
    sVertex* dst = new sVertex(iDataForDestination);
    vector<sVertex*> edge(m_iNoOfVertices);
    edge.push_back(dst);
    src->m_visited = WHITE;

    std::pair<std::map<sVertex, vector<sVertex*> >::iterator,bool> ret;

    m_mapAdjList.insert(pair<sVertex,vector<sVertex*> >(*src,edge));



    ret = m_mapAdjList.insert ( std::pair<sVertex, vector<sVertex*> >(src, dst) );

}

}
```

How can I implement adjency list using STL in C++?

Question is my initial design is right?
If not guide me in right direction.

Provide me sample code

Thanks

Comment: There is another StackExchange site regarding code reviews.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal The question says "I am new to STL and require help in add edge function." Code Review **requires working code**. This question does not belong on Code Review.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg , that's why I put up a comment instead of answer , and I was reading these lines 'Question is my initial design is right? If not guide me in right direction. ' :)

Comment: Maybe http://opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp/12_2_Graph_as_Collection_Li.html has enough hints to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things in your implementation

- You use dynamic memory, but this is not really necessary. Just add vertexes to the `std::vector`

  ```
  std::map<sVertex, std::vector<sVertex> > m_mapAdjList;
  ```
- You always create a new entry, overwriting an old one, if it already exists in the graph. So first check, if a vertex already exists in the graph. Your `addEdge()` might look something like

  ```
  void CGraph::addEdge(int iDataForSource, int iDataForDestination) {
      sVertex src(iDataForSource), dst(iDataForDestination);
      auto &edge = m_mapAdjList[src];
      edge.push_back(dst);
  }
  ```

  And you need an appropriate comparison operator for `sVertex`, of course.